# There is a way to create a named schedule after a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I need to create a job whith DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB using the EXCLUDE CLAUSE to exclude the dates of table (holidays, it have 2 columns date and ).
I tried to create a named schedule after this table, there is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: The table that I want to use has two columns, a date and a string.

Comment: [`create_schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-91D53EDA-72FD-452F-891B-FE266CAC8615) subprogram has no relationship with the table or any other database object: schedule_name, start_date, repeat_interval,  end_date, comments - these are all available parameters. Please clarify your requirement

Comment: I have a job that shouldn't run on holidays.
I have a list of holidays in a table.
I tried to use this list in the exclude clause and I couldn't. Do you have any suggestions on the best way to prevent the job from running on the days listed in this table?
I did an if in the procedure performed by the scheduled job so that it stops when the sysdate is equal to one day of the holiday table, but I believe it is not the best approach, I would like to use the exclude clause of the schedule itself.

Comment: You have clarified your problem in comments, but if comments accumulate, they get lost in the list of comments. It's better if you edit your question adding all the relevant details so it can be understood in the future.